# Can I use TOP and Count in a single SELECT of SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, count

I am using SQL Server2008R2. I have below SQL select statement:

```
select column1, max(column2), min(column3)
from myTable
group by column1
order by column1
```

Let's say the above select statement returns 1001 records.

Let it return `TOP 5` is not hard:

```
select top 5 column1, max(column2), min(column3)
from myTable
group by column1
order by column1
```

How can I modify the above statement so 1001 will also return and hence I know how many records in total?
I want some result like this:

```
1001 column1 max(column2) min(column3) -- top#1 row data
1001 column2 max(column2) min(column3) -- top#2 row data
1001 column1 max(column2) min(column3) -- top#3 row data
1001 column2 max(column2) min(column3) -- top#4 row data
1001 column2 max(column2) min(column3) -- top#5 row data
```

1001 is the total number of available records, and I only select top 5 of them. I want to know the total number and the details for top 5.

Comment: Do a sub-select for the first column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is with a subquery:

```
select top 5 *
from (select count(*) over () as cnt, column1, max(column2), min(column3)
      from myTable
      group by column1
     ) t
order by column1;
```

Although I prefer the subquery to prevent ambiguity, it also works without the subquery:

```
      select top 5 count(*) over () as cnt, column1, max(column2), min(column3)
      from myTable
      group by column1
      order by column1;
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `count() over()` window function..

```
select top 5 
    count(*) over (),
    column1, 
    max(column2), 
    min(column3)
from myTable
group by column1
order by column1
```